# oracle apex redirect to page from javascript code

Tags: javascript, redirect, oracle-apex

I try to pop up to a page, with this javascript code. but as you can see I want to bring the id value along with the pop up that is opened, but as it doesn't matter,

```js
javascript:popupURL('f?p=&APP_ID.:392:&SESSION.::NO::P392_MERCHANT_ID:&P223_MERCHANT_ID.');
```

I've tried looking for references like this is the right way or am I making a mistake?

Comment: Should there be a `.` after P392_MERCHANT_ID ?

Comment: yes, if it doesn't end with "." it will generate a Bad Request
The request could not be understood by server due to malformed syntax.

Comment: It also has to start with `&`.  Everything between `&` and `.` is the replacement variable, so you must specify both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked by OTN test applications, and this is how I've handled popups.

In the page's HTML Header section, I would put:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function openPopup()
{
  var url;
  url = 'f?p=&APP_ID.:392:&SESSION.::NO::P392_MERCHANT_ID:&P223_MERCHANT_ID.';
  w = open(url,"winLov","Scrollbars=1,resizable=1,width=800,height=600");
  if (w.opener == null)
  w.opener = self;
  w.focus();
}
</script>
```

Then, I add a Text Field page item to the page and put the following in its Post Text setting:

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:openPopup();">Popup</a>
```

This provides a link that the user can click to open the popup.

Comment: maybe I'm not careful, and I've added it still doesn't work

Comment: Are you trying to set P392_MERCHANT_ID on page 392 to the value of P223_MERCHANT_ID on page 223 (which would likely be the current page)?

Comment: Actually, your original string looks correct - as long as you are passing P223_MERCHANT_ID into P392_MERCHANT_ID on page 392.  Are both items correctly named?  Is, P223_MERCHANT_ID on the current page?

Comment: yes, P223_MERCHANT_ID is on the current page, I'm trying to bring the merchant_id together when the pop up window is activated, so don't have to manually set it on page 392 on P392_MERCHANT_ID, will it work with the current code?

Comment: OK - whenever I did a popup, I would prepare the URL first - using [prepare url](https://docs.oracle.com/database/apex-5.1/AEAPI/PREPARE_URL-Function.htm#AEAPI160)

Comment: Is your popup being called by clicking a `<a>` tag item on the page?

Comment: no, I run it directly by writing **javascript: popupURL**

Comment: But, how does the user trigger that?  They have to click something on page 223 to open the popup?

Comment: So, I use the enable and disable dynamic action, when the user selects enable a popup (page 392) will appear.
and this case has been successful, I tried to manually set the id_merchant value on page 392 with max + 1, but it seems this method is not very effective,

Comment: OK - I've just updated my Answer with what I have done in the past for popups.  Most of mine were from a field in a report, but this one is for a link from a Text Item on the page itself.  Is that the sort of thing you are trying to do?

Comment: yes that's right, and when page 392 is called, P392_MERCHANT_ID already contains the latest value of P223_MERCHANT_ID, at least that's what I understand and try to do at this point

Comment: OK - then try using what I have entered into this Answer.  That should set the value of P392_MERCHANT_ID when the popup is being loaded.

Comment: OK - if you don't already have one, I would suggest requesting an OTN workspace [OTN Workspace](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/otn/f?p=4550:1).  In there, you can create test applications and try out the different functionalities of Apex.

Comment: i really appreciate it, i definitely give it a try